# Sort a clist and calculating the sign of the sorting permutation

Tags: latex3, sorting

I want to sort a LaTeX3 clist and, at the same time, calculate the sign of the sorting permutation, which is `(-n)^s` where `s` is the number of swaps required to sort the list.

For example, if I start with `23,7,18,17,16,15,8,6,19,4,3,2` then the sign is `+1` as I can sort this list by first swapping `7` and `19` and then swapping `6` and `7`.

Using LaTeX3 I thought that I could do this using something like:

```
\clist_gsort:Nn \g_test_clist
{
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 > #2 }
    { \sort_return_same: }
    {
      \int_gset:Nn \g_sign_int {\int_eval:n {\g_sign_int*-1}}
      \sort_return_swapped:
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, even though this often works it sometimes fails and, in particular, it fails with the list above. My interpretation of the MWE below is that LaTeX sorts this list by performing the following sequence of swaps:

- swap 7 and 17 to give `23,17,18,7,16,15,8,6,19,4,3,2`
- swap 8 and 8 to give  `23,17,18,8,16,15,7,6,19,4,3,2`
- swap 6 and 19 to give `23,17,18,8,16,15,7,19,6,4,3,2`
- swap 7 and 19 to give `23,17,18,8,16,15,19,7,6,4,3,2`
- swap 8 and 19 to give `23,17,18,19,16,15,8,7,6,4,3,2`
- swap 15 and 19 to give `23,17,18,15,16,19,8,7,6,4,3,2` *
- swap 16 and 19 to give `23,17,18,15,19,16,8,7,6,4,3,2`
- swap 17 and 19 to give `23,19,18,15,17,16,8,7,6,4,3,2`
- swap 18 and 19 to give `23,18,19,15,17,16,8,7,6,4,3,2` *

Clearly, I do not understand what is going on here as the last sequence is not sorted, and nor does it agree with the final sequence returned by LaTeX, which is correctly sorted. The two swaps marked with an asterisk are problematic as by my understanding they should not happen. The code also returns the wrong sign.

My two questions are:

1. What is really going on here
2. Is it possible to use `\clist_gsort:Nn`, or some other technique, to compute the sign of the sorting permutation.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=4mm

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N  \g_test_clist
\clist_gset:Nn \g_test_clist {23,7,18,17,16,15,8,6,19,4,3,2}

\int_new:N   \g_sign_int
\int_gset:Nn \g_sign_int {1}

Initial~list~\clist_use:Nn \g_test_clist {,}.\newline
Initial~sign:~$\int_use:N \g_sign_int$.\par

\clist_gsort:Nn \g_test_clist
{
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 > #2 }
    { \sort_return_same: }
    {
      \int_gset:Nn \g_sign_int {\int_eval:n {\g_sign_int*-1}}
      Swapping:~#1~and~#2:~new~sign$=\int_use:N \g_sign_int$.\newline
      \sort_return_swapped:
    }
}
\par
Final~list:~\clist_use:Nn \g_test_clist {,}.\newline
Final~sign:~$\int_use:N \g_sign_int$.

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be assuming a bubble sort - `l3sort` uses a merge sort

Comment: @JosephWright Ah, OK, thanks that makes sense. There does not seem to be an easy way to count inversions using the comparisions in a merge sort so I'll have to do this differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joeseph points out, `\clist_sort:Nn` uses a merge sort. As far as I can see there is no easy way to work out the sign of the sorting permutation using the comparisions used by the sort, so I need to do this differently. I actually only need the sign, and not the sorted list. The code below gives one way to find the sign, which is `(-1)^s` where `s` is the number of inversions in the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=4mm

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N  \l_test_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_test_clist {23,7,18,17,16,15,8,6,19,4,3,2}

\int_new:N \l_i_int
\int_new:N \l_j_int
\int_new:N \l_sign_int
\cs_new:Nn \__compute_sign_of_test_clist: {
  % increment \l_sign_int for every inversion in \l_test_clist
  \int_set:Nn \l_sign_int {0}
  \int_set:Nn \l_i_int {1}
  \int_until_do:nNnn {\l_i_int} = {\clist_count:N \l_test_clist}
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_j_int {\int_eval:n {\l_i_int} }
    \int_until_do:nNnn {\l_j_int} = {\clist_count:N \l_test_clist}
    {
      \int_incr:N \l_j_int
      \int_compare:nT { \clist_item:Nn\l_test_clist{\l_i_int} < \clist_item:Nn\l_test_clist{\l_j_int} }
      {
        \int_incr:N \l_sign_int
      }
    }
    \int_incr:N \l_i_int
  }
  \int_if_even:nTF {\l_sign_int} {+}{-}
}

List~\clist_use:Nn \l_test_clist {,}.\newline
Sign:~$\__compute_sign_of_test_clist:$

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare items starting from the leftmost one, then dropping it and restart the comparisons until there are no more items.

Each time there is an inversion, I increment the counter; eventually, I check the parity and return 1 or minus 1 accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\computesign}{m}
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_pi_sign_int
  \pi_sign_compute:n { #1 }
  \ensuremath { \int_if_odd:nTF { \l_pi_sign_int } { -1 } { 1 } }
 }

\clist_new:N \l__pi_sign_clist
\int_new:N \l_pi_sign_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pi_sign_compute:n
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l__pi_sign_clist { #1 }
  \__pi_sign_compute:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pi_sign_compute:
 {
  \clist_pop:NN \l__pi_sign_clist \l__pi_sign_first_tl
  \clist_if_empty:NF \l__pi_sign_clist
   {
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__pi_sign_clist
     {
      \int_compare:nT { \l__pi_sign_first_tl < ##1 } { \int_incr:N \l_pi_sign_int }
     }
    % restart the recursion
    \__pi_sign_compute:
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\computesign{23,7,18,17,16,15,8,6,19,4,3,2}

\computesign{23,7,18,17,16,15,8,6,19,4,2,3}

\computesign{1,2}

\computesign{2,1}

\computesign{1,2,3}

\computesign{1,2,3,4}

\computesign{1}

\computesign{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As in my MWE, I have the data stored in a clist for a reason and popping the items off it destroys the original clist, which I don't want to do so (my essentially equivalent) approach is better for my purposes.

Comment: @31415926535897932384 Just copy the `clist` in a scratch one.

Comment: Actually, I am using the code that I posted before you posted yours....